# Replace where a value occurs in a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I want to replace the value of "Carl" with the value "Karl".

I am sure this is easy but I can't figure it out! (I am more used to Python than R). 
Code extract is as below:

```
name <- c("Amy", "Bill", "Carl")

DAD <- c(80, 65, 50)
BDA <- c(70, 50, 80)

gender <- as.factor(c("F", "M", "M"))
nationality <- as.factor(c("IRL", "UK", "IRL"))
age <- c(20, 21, 22)

student.df <- data.frame(name, age, gender, nationality, DAD, BDA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can just do an assignment by creating logical vector from 'name' using `==`

```
student.df$name[student.df$name == 'Carl'] <- 'Karl'
student.df
#  name age gender nationality DAD BDA
#1  Amy  20      F         IRL  80  70
#2 Bill  21      M          UK  65  50
#3 Karl  22      M         IRL  50  80
```

Comment: I tried that and get the below error: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, student.df$name == "Carl", value = c(1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: convert `name` to character before running the code from @akrun: `student.df$name <- as.character(student.df$name)`

Comment: Yes I had just figured that out this second! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
student.df %>% 
  mutate(name = if_else(name == "Carl", "Karl", name))

  name age gender nationality DAD BDA
1  Amy  20      F         IRL  80  70
2 Bill  21      M          UK  65  50
3 Karl  22      M         IRL  50  80
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, ideally I would like to do it using base R rather than dplyr.